# How can I use a stream with a regular provider, updating the local values as the stream is delivered

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

So I have something like this which works fine with streamprovider.

```
Stream<List<AppUser>> streamUsers() {
    return firestore.collection('users').snapshots().map(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.docs
              .map((document) => AppUser.fromJson(document.data()))
              .toList(),
        );
  }
```

What I'm looking to achieve is something like this, where the stream will run in the background, and everytime data is transmitted it updates a local variable in my provider and notifies my widgets through provider that way. Is it bad idea? If so, why?

```
class AppUsers with ChangeNotifier {
  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  List<AppUser> _users;

  List<AppUser> get users => _users;

  void streamUsers() {
    List<AppUser> users = [];
    firestore
        .collection('users')
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs.map((document) {
              AppUser user = AppUser.fromJson(document.data());
              users.add(user);
            }));
    _users = users;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

UPDATE

I was able to achieve this with the following code and calling init() when my app loads. I want to avoid calling init when my app loads tho. Is there a cleaner way?

```
  List<AppUser> _users = [];

  List<AppUser> get users => _users;

  init() {
    streamUsers().listen((event) {
      _users = event;
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  Stream<List<AppUser>> streamUsers() {
    return firestore.collection('users').snapshots().map(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.docs
              .map((document) => AppUser.fromJson(document.data()))
              .toList(),
        );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the init function and use notify listener every stream event by mapping once more :

```dart
 Stream<List<AppUser>> streamUsers() {
    return firestore.collection('users').snapshots().map(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.docs
              .map((document) => AppUser.fromJson(document.data()))
              .toList(),
        ).map((users) {
         _users = users;
         notifyListeners();
    });
  }
```